# django loginview csrftoken fobidden error

Tags: django, ajax, loginview

I'd like to ask you a question about the Loginview of Django.

I'm using the Loginview as it is.

There's a problem, but I'll open two browser tabs and leave them open as login pages (the same browser )

When I log in first from one browser tab and log in from another browser tab (both are the same browser), the csrf_token error appears, which is 403 Forbidden error!

The way I want to do it is to log in without errors even if I log in from another browser tab if I'm already logged in from one browser tab.

Also, I'm trying to solve it using Ajax, but I'm not familiar with it, so I'm having a hard time solving the problem.

How should I solve this?

Comment: Any specific reason why you need to login from both the tabs? 
Ideally If you login from 1 tab and hit refresh on the 2nd tab, the 2nd tab should automatically be logged in.

Comment: There is no specific reason. However, this is because I don't want to show the error from the user's point of view.

Comment: In that case, I feel it should be fine. Majorly because, users wont open two tabs and try to sign in to it. Or you could catch the error in a middleware and show it with a specific page for the user.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you so much!! I really appreciate!!! :D